# Remove entries from data frame when two columns are repeated, retaining the one with highest value in a third column

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, subset

I have a data frame with some entries that have the same ID and TYPE value, when ID+TYPE should be my unique key. I need to filter out those entries that have a repeated ID and TYPE value, looking at a third column to decide which entry to retain and which to discard.

The data frame looks like this:

```
mydf <- data.frame(ID=c('A1','B6','C3','C3','E8','D4','G1','B6','C1','C1'),
                     TYPE=c('class','genus','order','order','class','genus','species','genus','family','order'),
                     STRING=c('a;a;a','b;b','c;c;c;c','c;c;c','e;e;e;e','d;d','g;g;g','b;b;b;b;b','c;c;c;c','c;c'),
                     VALUE=c(34,435,876,23,5,7,77,42,233,500))


mydf
   ID    TYPE    STRING VALUE
1  A1   class     a;a;a    34
2  B6   genus       b;b   435
3  C3   order   c;c;c;c   876
4  C3   order     c;c;c    23
5  E8   class   e;e;e;e     5
6  D4   genus       d;d     7
7  G1 species     g;g;g    77
8  B6   genus b;b;b;b;b    42
9  C1  family   c;c;c;c   233
10 C1   order       c;c   500
```

So entries for C3+order and B6+genus are repeated. I would like to test two ways of selecting which to retain:

1- the one of the two (or more in my real data frame) with the highest VALUE

2- the one of the two (or more) with the shortest number of elements in STRING separated by comma (not necessarily the shortest nchar)

From 1 I should obtain the following (without entries 4 and 8):

```
mydf
   ID    TYPE    STRING VALUE
1  A1   class     a;a;a    34
2  B6   genus       b;b   435
3  C3   order   c;c;c;c   876
5  E8   class   e;e;e;e     5
6  D4   genus       d;d     7
7  G1 species     g;g;g    77
9  C1  family   c;c;c;c   233
10 C1   order       c;c   500
```

From 2 I should obtain the following (without entries 3 and 8):

```
mydf
   ID    TYPE    STRING VALUE
1  A1   class     a;a;a    34
2  B6   genus       b;b   435
4  C3   order     c;c;c    23
5  E8   class   e;e;e;e     5
6  D4   genus       d;d     7
7  G1 species     g;g;g    77
9  C1  family   c;c;c;c   233
10 C1   order       c;c   500
```

Any clue on how to obtain these subsets, filtering out those entries? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dplyr`, you can do something like this:

```
mydf %>% group_by(ID, TYPE) %>% filter(VALUE == max(VALUE))

# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   ID, TYPE [8]
#      ID    TYPE  STRING VALUE
#  <fctr>  <fctr>  <fctr> <dbl>
#1     A1   class   a;a;a    34
#2     B6   genus     b;b   435
#3     C3   order c;c;c;c   876
#4     E8   class e;e;e;e     5
#5     D4   genus     d;d     7
#6     G1 species   g;g;g    77
#7     C1  family c;c;c;c   233
#8     C1   order     c;c   500

library(stringr)
mydf %>% 
    group_by(ID, TYPE) %>% 
    filter(str_count(STRING, ";") == min(str_count(STRING, ";")))

# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   ID, TYPE [8]
#      ID    TYPE  STRING VALUE
#  <fctr>  <fctr>  <fctr> <dbl>
#1     A1   class   a;a;a    34
#2     B6   genus     b;b   435
#3     C3   order   c;c;c    23
#4     E8   class e;e;e;e     5
#5     D4   genus     d;d     7
#6     G1 species   g;g;g    77
#7     C1  family c;c;c;c   233
#8     C1   order     c;c   500
```

For the second part, if you care about efficiency:

```
mydf %>% 
    group_by(ID, TYPE) %>% 
    mutate(n_semicolon = str_count(STRING, ";")) %>% 
    filter(n_semicolon == min(n_semicolon)) %>% 
    select(-n_semicolon)

# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   ID, TYPE [8]
#      ID    TYPE  STRING VALUE
#  <fctr>  <fctr>  <fctr> <dbl>
#1     A1   class   a;a;a    34
#2     B6   genus     b;b   435
#3     C3   order   c;c;c    23
#4     E8   class e;e;e;e     5
#5     D4   genus     d;d     7
#6     G1 species   g;g;g    77
#7     C1  family c;c;c;c   233
#8     C1   order     c;c   500
```

Comment: I am not really familiar with this format returned, how do I access only the data.frame? Thanks!

Comment: You can convert it to a normal data frame by chaining the `as.data.frame` method at the end. ` ... %>% as.data.frame`

Comment: just figured it, I added  "%>%   as.data.frame()" at the end!

Comment: Sometimes I have NA values in the STRING column, is it possible to retain those rows, instead of removing them as it is doing now?

Comment: You can add a or condition in the filter. `filter(str_count(STRING, ";") == min(str_count(STRING, ";")) | is.na(STRING))`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

**1)**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[, .SD[which.max(VALUE)], .(ID, TYPE)]
#   ID    TYPE  STRING VALUE
#1: A1   class   a;a;a    34
#2: B6   genus     b;b   435
#3: C3   order c;c;c;c   876
#4: E8   class e;e;e;e     5
#5: D4   genus     d;d     7
#6: G1 species   g;g;g    77
#7: C1  family c;c;c;c   233
#8: C1   order     c;c   500
```

**2)**

```
setDT(mydf)[, n := nchar(gsub("[^;]+", "", STRING))
     ][, .SD[n == min(n)], .(ID, TYPE)][, n := NULL][]
#    ID    TYPE  STRING VALUE
#1: A1   class   a;a;a    34
#2: B6   genus     b;b   435
#3: C3   order   c;c;c    23
#4: E8   class e;e;e;e     5
#5: D4   genus     d;d     7
#6: G1 species   g;g;g    77
#7: C1  family c;c;c;c   233
#8: C1   order     c;c   500
```